# Merge Point Data and Raster using ST_SetValues in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to merge a point dataset with a raster dataset using Column X / Row Y.

I have written a tool which generates a raster and, from that raster, I have created grid points with `St_PixelsAsCentroids()`. These pixel centroids then undergo their own analysis (see image below) which I then want to merge back onto the raster. I know I can do this using `geomval` and `ST_SetValues()` but was wondering if there was a quicker way to relate back to the original raster's Column X / Row Y?

[image: Analysed raster pixel centroids reading to be returned to the mother raster!]

Answer (score 1):

Still not clear what you are trying to do.  ST_SetValues does have a variant that takes a matrix of values (where the matrix positions correspond to x/y column). So if you know the X/Y you can just fill it in with the matrix of values instead of using geomval. http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_SetValues.html

There are other ways of burning pixel values into an existing raster. You can use a combination of ST_Union(ST_AsRaster) and convert all your existing geometries to rasters and union them in with the original. If you have more of a sparse matrix that might be much speedier than using ST_SetValues.  I haven't done any benchmarks to see which performs better.

Comment: "So if you know the X/Y you can just fill it in with the matrix of values instead of using geomval."

I have read the documentation and couldn't figure this one out. Could you post the code?